# Ruby formula issue with my variable

Tags: ruby

What is wrong with my variable declaration ?

```
puts("lets see how well you know ruby")
name = gets
name = name.chomp
if name == Alex
  print("good job")
else 
  print("leave")
end
```

Error:

```
(st.txt:5:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Alex (NameError)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include Alex in quotes. If you don't include it in quotes, it thinks that it's a `constant` named `Alex`

Change:

```
if name == Alex
```

To:

```
if name == "Alex"
```

And your code should work fine.

As a side note, variables starting with a capital letter are constants, and generally aren't changed.

Answer (score 1):

it should be `'Alex'`, not `Alex`. Because `Alex` would be a constant (pointing to a class, module or whatever else), not a string.

What you get here

```
name = name.chomp
```

will always return a string (empty or nonempty depending on whether you've entered anything or not).

In Ruby exceptions usually have great explanation of what is going on, so reading these is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:)

```
puts("lets see how well you know ruby")
name = gets.chomp
if name == /alex/
  print("good job")
else 
  print("leave")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixing and refactoring your code, try:

```
puts "lets see how well you know ruby"
name = gets.chomp
puts name == "Alex" ? "good job" : "leave"
```

If you want to know more about the notation on the last line, search *ternary operator*.